# ProxyPass: как избежать превращения Apache в "open proxy"

Tags: apache, безопасность, proxy

Подскажите, как правильно настроить `ProxyPass` в *Apache*.

Сейчас стоят настройки для `centerix.ru`: `ProxyRequests On` и `ProxyPass /wiki/ http://wiki.centerix.ru/wiki/`. Также стоял глобальный `ProxyRequests On`. С какого-то момента все начало дико тормозить. Разбор полетов показал, что `ProxyRequests On` разрешает не только `ProxyPass`, но и проксирование всех запросов, чем и воспользовалась какая-то сеть ботов. После выключения глобального `ProxyRequests` зависания прекратились, но, я полагаю, что через `centerix.ru` все равно остается возможность проксирования соединений.

`ProxyPass` хочет `ProxyRequests On`, `ProxyRequests On` разрешает проксирование всего. Как оставить `ProxyPass`, но запретить использование апача как прокси?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте не глобальный `proxyrequests`, а поместите его внутрь *virtualhost-а*, для которого ограничьте обработку лишь нужными `servername` и `serveralias`.

в документации как к [версии 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests), так и к [версии 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests) написано, что область применения — либо глобальная, либо внутри *virtualhost-а*:

> Context:  server config, virtual host

Comment: А, дошло. Не сообразил, что виртуалхост будет срабатывать только при запросе домена указанного в servername.